# COUNT(*) takes long even after deleting all rows

Tags: mysql, count, delete-row, sql-delete

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Sdata(uid INTEGER, timestamp DATETIME, value REAL, FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES Series_uid(uid));
```

At one point, this table had ~90M rows.
I queried for `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sdata;` which took about 7 minutes.

Then I proceeded to `DELETE FROM Sdata;`. This query took over an hour, which is understandable given the large size.
After deleting all rows from `Sdata`, I ran the `COUNT` again. This time it still took about 7 minutes.

I'm confused as to why the `COUNT` still takes a while even though the table is now empty. What is going on here?

Comment: Which storage engine?

Comment: All the tables are using InnoDB.

Comment: I'm not 100% on MySQL, hence why this is a comment rather than an answer, however: Try using `TRUNCATE SData` rather than `DELETE FROM SData` - `DELETE FROM` will empty the table but may not entirely clean it up. `TRUNCATE` actually internally drops and rebuilds the table (if you have an auto-increment identity field on it, it will also reset to 1). Also try `OPTIMIZE TABLE SData`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After `DELETE FROM Sdata` try using `OPTIMIZE TABLE Sdata` to really discard the unused rows, or in the future, use `TRUNCATE Sdata` which will do this automatically for you.

Quote from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html):

> In MyISAM tables, deleted rows are maintained in a linked list and subsequent INSERT operations reuse old row positions. To reclaim unused space and reduce file sizes, use the OPTIMIZE TABLE statement or the myisamchk utility to reorganize tables.